# Simulator crashes during test in CI only

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, automated-tests, buddy-build

Almost very frequently, I'm getting crashes on my CI builds that run unit and UI tests of my application with following crashlog:

```
Process:               trustd [9695]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-<CI redacted>0.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/trustd
Identifier:            trustd
Version:               58286.252.<CI redacted>
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [9623]
Responsible:           trustd [9695]
User ID:               50<CI redacted>

Date/Time:             20<CI redacted>9-04-25 11:22:25.903 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X <CI redacted>0.14.4 (18E226)
Report Version:        <CI redacted>2
Anonymous UUID:        E9BB8D2<CI redacted>-3445-8FCA-693D-F07E58EF8057


Time Awake Since Boot: <CI redacted>900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        6  Dispatch queue: com.apple.MobileAsset.client.asyncmessage

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000<CI redacted>000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: <CI redacted>1
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [9695]

VM Regions Near 0x<CI redacted>000000000:
    SQLite page cache      0000000<CI redacted>14575000-0000000114585000 [   64K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> 
    STACK GUARD            000070000b933000-000070000b934000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 0

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 587.35 - Device: Clone 2 of iPhone Xs Max (AD46929A-F753-4DDE-9F37-AFB36EC23052) - Runtime: iOS <CI redacted>2.2 (16E226) - DeviceType: iPhone Xs Max

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000<CI redacted>109ba3f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread <CI redacted>:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000<CI redacted>10968126 __sigsuspend_nocancel + 10
<CI redacted>   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001105e9854 _dispatch_sigsuspend + 21
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000<CI redacted>105e983f _dispatch_sig_thread + 55

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000<CI redacted>1096422a mach_msg_trap + 10
<CI redacted>   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000011096476c mach_msg + 60
2   libsystem_notify.dylib          0x0000000<CI redacted>108a0dc4 notify_check + 263
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000<CI redacted>107246da notify_check_tz + 44
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000<CI redacted>107242e3 tzsetwall_basic + 45
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000<CI redacted>10726262 localtime_r + 41
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000<CI redacted>0dacc74b _populateBanner + 91
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000<CI redacted>0daca1c7 _CFLogvEx2Predicate + 391
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000<CI redacted>0daca411 _CFLogvEx3 + 369
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x0000000<CI redacted>0dfb81aa _NSLogv + 104
<CI redacted>0  com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010dfb8242 NSLog + 132
<CI redacted>1  com.apple.MobileAssets          0x000000010cfb3ace __setClientConnectionHandler_block_invoke + 162
<CI redacted>2  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000110906a90 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 56
<CI redacted>3  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000110906c57 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 446
<CI redacted>4  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001105d8da2 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 9
<CI redacted>5  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001105f243a _dispatch_mach_cancel_invoke + 65
<CI redacted>6  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001105ef903 _dispatch_mach_invoke + 1086
<CI redacted>7  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001105e8fcb _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 645
<CI redacted>8  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001109ba611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
<CI redacted>9  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001109ba3fd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:: Dispatch queue: /Library/Keychains/crls/valid.sqlite3
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000<CI redacted>109aa530 _platform_bzero$VARIANT$Ivybridge + 48
<CI redacted>   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000010d90e021 purgeableCacheFetch + 1073
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000<CI redacted>0d8510b6 getPageNormal + 54
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000<CI redacted>0d813fd4 sqlite3BtreeBeginTrans + 884
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000<CI redacted>0d979125 sqlite3InitOne + 805
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000<CI redacted>0d8b7647 sqlite3Pragma + 3351
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000<CI redacted>0d88c065 yy_reduce + 9893
7   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000<CI redacted>0d8220e5 sqlite3RunParser + 533
8   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000<CI redacted>0d81fd34 sqlite3LockAndPrepare + 900
9   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000<CI redacted>0d810b0b sqlite3_prepare_v2 + 43
<CI redacted>0  trustd                          0x000000010ceb86b3 _SecDbOpenV2 + 171
<CI redacted>1  trustd                          0x000000010ceb8431 __SecDbOpenHandle_block_invoke + 69
<CI redacted>2  trustd                          0x000000010ceb835c SecDbOpenHandle + 166
<CI redacted>3  trustd                          0x000000010ceb96d6 __SecDbConnectionAcquireRefMigrationSafe_block_invoke.47 + 366
<CI redacted>4  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001105d8d02 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
<CI redacted>5  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001105e55fd _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 94
<CI redacted>6  trustd                          0x000000010ceb93bc SecDbConnectionAcquireRefMigrationSafe + 391
<CI redacted>7  trustd                          0x000000010ceba018 SecDbPerformRead + 44
<CI redacted>8  trustd                          0x000000010cedadb8 SecRevocationDbPerformRead + 152
<CI redacted>9  trustd                          0x000000010cee0c5b __SecRevocationDbCopyUpdateSource_block_invoke + 73
20  trustd                          0x0000000<CI redacted>0ceda1c9 SecRevocationDbCopyUpdateSource + 95
2<CI redacted>  trustd                          0x000000010cee1eed __SecRevocationDbCheckNextUpdate_block_invoke_2 + 775
22  trustd                          0x0000000<CI redacted>0cebc7e9 _sec_action_event + 21
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000<CI redacted>105d8d02 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000<CI redacted>105db6be _dispatch_continuation_pop + 440
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000<CI redacted>105eb997 _dispatch_source_invoke + 2072
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000<CI redacted>105df58d _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 302
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000<CI redacted>105e0297 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 452
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000<CI redacted>105e8fcb _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 645
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000<CI redacted>109ba611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
30  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000<CI redacted>109ba3fd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000<CI redacted>109ba3f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000<CI redacted>109ba3f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.MobileAsset.client.asyncmessage
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000<CI redacted>1088269a tiny_malloc_from_free_list + 340
<CI redacted>   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000110880bb8 tiny_malloc_should_clear + 229
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000<CI redacted>10866c08 szone_malloc_should_clear + 66
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000<CI redacted>10871da8 malloc_zone_malloc + 103
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000<CI redacted>10872558 malloc + 24
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000<CI redacted>10915f6d _xpc_malloc + 47
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000<CI redacted>109099f4 _xpc_dictionary_insert + 346
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000<CI redacted>1090a080 xpc_dictionary_set_int64 + 41
8   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x0000000<CI redacted>108cc3b9 _os_activity_stream_reflect + 569
9   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x0000000<CI redacted>108d8ed1 _os_log_impl_stream + 583
<CI redacted>0  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001108d8554 _os_log_impl_flatten_and_send + 5670
<CI redacted>1  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001108d9d80 _os_log_with_args_impl + 491
<CI redacted>2  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010daca4d9 _CFLog_os_log_shim + 89
<CI redacted>3  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010daca343 _CFLogvEx3 + 163
<CI redacted>4  com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010dfb81aa _NSLogv + 104
<CI redacted>5  com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010dfb8242 NSLog + 132
<CI redacted>6  com.apple.MobileAssets          0x000000010cfb4096 __sendAsync_block_invoke + 304
<CI redacted>7  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000011091186e _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 36
<CI redacted>8  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001109065a8 _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 86
<CI redacted>9  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001105d8d6c _dispatch_client_callout3 + 8
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000<CI redacted>105f0468 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke + 332
2<CI redacted>  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001105df58d _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 302
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000<CI redacted>105e0261 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 398
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000<CI redacted>105e8fcb _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 645
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000<CI redacted>109ba611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000<CI redacted>109ba3fd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00000000000000<CI redacted>9  rdx: 0x0000000100000000
  rdi: 0x0000000<CI redacted>127ee080  rsi: 0x00000000a9fbc5ba  rbp: 0x000070000bcc3920  rsp: 0x000070000bcc38f0
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x000000<CI redacted>000000000  r10: 0x00007fefeae00000  r11: 0x00007feeda524aff
  r<CI redacted>2: 0x0000000000000004  r13: 0x00007fefeae02930  r14: 0x0000000000000004  r15: 0x00000001127f0a00
  rip: 0x0000000<CI redacted>1088269a  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x000070000bc3c168

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000<CI redacted>70
Trap Number:     <CI redacted>33


Binary Images:
 ...

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 28925
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=82.2M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=82.2M(<CI redacted>00%)
Writable regions: Total=42.6M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=42.6M(<CI redacted>00%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        <CI redacted> 
Dispatch continuations            <CI redacted>024K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        <CI redacted> 
MALLOC                            37.0M       <CI redacted>5 
MALLOC guard page                   <CI redacted>6K        4 
SQLite page cache                  256K        4 
STACK GUARD                         28K        7 
Stack                             3652K        9 
Stack Guard                       64.0M        2 
__DATA                            6948K      <CI redacted>15 
__DATA_DIRTY                        <CI redacted>6K        3 
__LINKEDIT                        <CI redacted>6.8M       91 
__TEXT                            65.4M       9<CI redacted> 
__UNICODE                          564K        <CI redacted> 
mapped file                       26.7M        7 
shared memory                       24K        3 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            222.4M      355
```

Not sure what's causing it or even where I should start for debugging for it. Any hints is highly appreciated. It doesn't happen when I run the tests locally.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: No, and I'm not at the same company anymore so not sure if it's been fixed by recent Xcode updates or not